# Compiling issues with minted: I can't write on file `thesis.pyg'

Tags: windows, minted, auxiliary-files, filesystem-access

In my thesis I am using minted
for listings and lots of short inline references.

I'm running TeXLive on Windows with python 3.6.
I am also using the cache, kpsewhich and outputdir options:

```
\usepackage[cache=true,kpsewhich=true,outputdir=pdflatex_out]{minted}
```

The more inline minted usages I have, the more often I get a compiler error

```
d:/Dropbox/Informatik/master-thesis/thesis/05-implementation-UAI-protocol.tex:2
76: I can't write on file `thesis.pyg'.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.276 ...supposed to await a \protobufinline|QUIT|
                                                   action
```

When I turn minteds caching off, it seems to work fine, but compiling takes ages.
I need kpeswitch as the document has several dependencies to other directories and I am building with some TEXINPUTS.

Also note, that the error position `l.102` is just an example: it seemingly randomly occurs at different positions, mostly where mintedinline commands are used.

I suppose it makes little sense to give a minimal example, as the problem only occurs in the huge document and the frequency is increase with the usage of minted commands.

Sadly I have no good idea how to beginn debugging this issue and could not find anything related.